# Manipulate JSON in Laravel 5 Middleware

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have an Ajax request which is sent to a Laravel 5 application.
But I need to reformat/change/... the JSON before I send it to the controller.

Is there a way to manipulate the request body (JSON) in the middleware?

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RequestManipulator {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->isJson())
        {
            $json = json_decode($request->getContent(), TRUE);
            //manipulate the json and set it again to the the request
            $manipulatedRequest = ....
            $request = $manipulatedRequest;
        }
        \Log::info($request);
        return $next($request); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). See ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)". BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible you have two types of middlewares, the ones that run before the request and the ones that run after the request, you can find more info about it [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware#defining-middleware).

To create a a middleware responsible for that you can generate one with this command:

```
php artisan make:middleware ProcessJsonMiddleware
```

Then register it with a friendly name on your kernel

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
        'process.json' => 'App\Http\Middleware\ProcessJsonMiddleware',
    ];
```

This middleware is just an example, it removes the last element of the array and replaces it on the request:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Tokenizer;

class ProcessJsonMiddleware {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->isJson())
        {
            //fetch your json data, instead of doing the way you were doing
            $json_array = $request->json()->all();

            //we have an array now let's remove the last element
            $our_last_element = array_pop($json_array);

            //now we replace our json data with our new json data without the last element
            $request->json()->replace($json_array);
        }

        return $next($request);

    }

}
```

On your controller fetch the json, not the content, or you will get the raw json without our filter:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    //var_dump and die our filtered json
    dd($request->json()->all());
}
```

Comment: there is a typo in your artisan command: ProcessJsontMiddleware

nice answer ;)

Comment: Oops, fixed it. Thanks

Comment: I've tried this with a custom Request for my validation instead of `Request` and it didn't work while it works for a \Illuminate\Http\Request. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: @lenny.myr Did you solve it with the custom Request? I have this same problem and it works only without the header `Content-Type: application/json` otherwise the custom Requests end up holding the original data.